# Change CSS of nth class in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the text color of the 5th `infobox` (class) in my code below. The text color changes but for all the infoboxes.

```js
//INFOBOX5
var json_data = {"headers":["Platform","Value1","value1","valueP1","valueP2"],"rows":[["platform2","xxx",404.07000000000005,1634,6364],["platform5","xxx",404.07000000000005,1634,6364],["platform1","xxx",352.8,1634,6364],["platform3","xxx",352.8,1634,6364],
["platform3","xxx",352.8,1634,6364],["platform4","xxx",352.8,1634,6364]]};

    var platform_data = json_data.rows;
    var platform1_element = document.getElementById("platform1");
    var platform5_element = document.getElementById("platform5");
    var platform6_element = document.getElementById("platform6");
    var platform2_element = document.getElementById("platform2");
    var platform3_element = document.getElementById("platform3");
    var platform4_element = document.getElementById("platform4");

    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }
    function formatNumber (num) {
        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
    }
    var platforms = [];
    for (var i in platform_data) {
        if (platform_data[i][0] != null){
            platforms[i] = platform_data[i][0].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
  
    var unique_platforms = platforms.filter( onlyUnique );

    var target_width = 100/(unique_platforms.length-2);
    var width_str=target_width+"%";

    platform1_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform5_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform6_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform3_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform2_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform4_element.classList.add("hidden");
   
    var total_value1 = 0;
    var total_value2 = 0;
    var total_display_value1 = 0;
    var total_video_value1 = 0;
    var total_mixed_value1 = 0;
    var total_other_value1 = 0;
    var total_display_value2 = 0;
    var total_video_value2 = 0;
    var total_mixed_value2 = 0;
    var value2_numbers = [];
    
    for (var i in unique_platforms) {
        var platform_name = unique_platforms[i].toLowerCase();

        var display_value1_total = 0;
        var display_value2_total = 0;
        var video_value1_total = 0;
        var video_value2_total = 0;
        var mixed_value1_total = 0;
        var mixed_value2_total = 0;
        var other_value1_total = 0;        

        for (var x in platform_data){
            if (platform_data[x][0] != null){
                    if(platform_data[x][0].toLowerCase() == platform_name){
                    switch(platform_data[x][1]) {
                        case "display":
                        // Red Dot
                        display_value1_total = display_value1_total + platform_data[x][2];
                        total_value1 = total_value1 + display_value1_total;
                        break;
                        case "video":
                        video_value1_total = video_value1_total + platform_data[x][2];
                        total_value1 = total_value1 + video_value1_total;
                        break;
                        case "mixed":
                        mixed_value1_total = mixed_value1_total + platform_data[x][2];
                        total_value1 = total_value1 + mixed_value1_total;
                        break;
                        case "Other":
                        other_value1_total = other_value1_total + platform_data[x][2];
                        total_value1 = total_value1 + other_value1_total;
                        break;
                        default:
                        doNothing = "";
                    }
                }
            }else {
                value2_numbers = platform_data[x];
            }            
        }

        var platform_value1 = display_value1_total + video_value1_total + mixed_value1_total + other_value1_total;
        var generic_element = document.getElementById(platform_name);

        var element_value1_name = platform_name+"_value1";
        var fl_value1 = parseFloat(platform_value1).toFixed(0);
        var curr_flag = "&euro;"+formatNumber(fl_value1);
        document.getElementById(element_value1_name).innerHTML = curr_flag;

        total_display_value1 = total_display_value1 + display_value1_total;
        total_video_value1 = total_video_value1 + video_value1_total;
        total_mixed_value1 = total_mixed_value1 + mixed_value1_total;
    }

    var total_value1_string = "<h1>&euro;" + formatNumber(Number(total_value1).toFixed(0)) + "</h1>";
    //document.getElementById("total_value1").innerHTML = total_value1_string;

  if (value2_numbers.length == 0){
      value2_numbers = platform_data[0];
  }
  var fl_value2 = 0;
  var curr_flag_bud = '';
  var element_value2_name = '';

  
  for (var i in json_data.headers){  
      switch(json_data.headers[i]) {
            case "valueP1":
                    element_value2_name = "platform1_value2";
                    fl_value2 = parseFloat(value2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&euro;"+formatNumber(fl_value2);
                    document.getElementById(element_value2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;
        case "valueP2":
                    element_value2_name = "platform2_value2";
                    fl_value2 = parseFloat(value2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&euro;" +formatNumber(fl_value2);
                    document.getElementById(element_value2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;    
           case "valueP1":
                    element_value2_name = "platform1_value2";
                    fl_value2 = parseFloat(value2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&euro;" +formatNumber(fl_value2);
                    document.getElementById(element_value2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;
                    default:
         } 
    }
    
    var statBox = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.infobox'));

    var element_id;
    
    var parentBoxlist = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.parentbox'));

    var channel_value1_check = 0;
    var value1_channels = [];

 //   if (total_mixed_value1 > 0.0) {channel_value1_check = channel_value1_check + 1;value1_channels[0] = 'mixed';};
 //   if (total_video_value1 > 0.0) {channel_value1_check = channel_value1_check + 1;value1_channels[1] = 'video';};
 //   if (total_display_value1 > 0.0) {channel_value1_check = channel_value1_check + 1;value1_channels[2] = 'display';};

    statBox.forEach(function(box) {
        switch(unique_platforms.length) {
            case 1:
                    // 1 box
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox1'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    // 2 box's
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox2'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    // 3 box's
                     element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox3'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;  
                    case 4:
                    // 4 box's
                     element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox4'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    // 5 box's
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox5'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    } 
                    break;
                    default:
                }
            });

$(".boxbox:nth-of-type(1)").css("color", "#fff");
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

    body{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    h1{
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    }
    h3{
    font-size: 1.1vw!important;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    .redSq{
    background-color: #ff000a;
    width: 117px;
    height: 241px;
    float:left;
    }
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 99.8%;
    height: 180px; 
    color: #454545;
    background-color:#dee9f3;
    //border: solid 1px #454545; 
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}
td{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#454545;
  font-weight:500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}
    .boxes{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 5%;
    min-width: 200px;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    #line{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .infobox {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    color: #454545;
    }

    .infobox1 {
    float:left;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    }

    .infobox2 {
    float:left;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width: 49%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox3 {
    float:left;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width: 32.33%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox4 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 23.9%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox5 {
    float:left;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width: 32.33%;
    margin: 0 0.5% 0.7%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    div.leftBox{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 1.1vw;    
    }
    div.rightBox{
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    }

    .infocontentheader {
    //text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.8;
    //color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    }

    .infocontent{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }


    div#platform1.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #3c5999;
    }

    div#platform1.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    p#sTitle {
         font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.5vw;
     }

     p#bTitle {
         //font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.2vw;
     }

     p#platform1_value1, p#platform5_value1, p#platform4_value1 ,p#platform3_value1, 
     p#platform2_value1, p#twitter_value1 {
         font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.3em;
         margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
     }

     p#platform1_budget, p#platform5_budget, p#platform4_budget, p#platform3_budget,
     p#platform2_budget, p#twitter_budget{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 10px 0 0 20px;        
     }

    div#twitter.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #1da1f2;
    }
    div#twitter.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }


    div#platform3.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #a15aa0;
    }

    div#display.parentbox{
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    color: #fff;
    }

    div#video.parentbox{
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #fff;
    }

    div#mixed.parentbox{
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: #fff;
    }

    #platform3 div.infocontentheader{
    color: #fff;
    }
    div#platform3.infobox img{

        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    div#platform3_value.infocontent{
    color: #000;
    }

    div#platform5.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #ff0102;
    }
    div#platform5.infobox img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    div#platform4.infocontentheader{
        background-color: #cac9c2;
    }
    div#platform4.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }
  div#platform2.infobox{
    background-color: #fff;
    }
    div#platform2.infobox img{
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }

    .hidden{
    display:none;
    }
    
    #parent_div_1{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #757476;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    #parent_div_2{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #8D8D8D;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox{
        width:33.33%;
        min-height: 150px;
        /*background-color: #8D8D8D;*/
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox1{
        width:100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox2{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox3{
        width:33.33%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .child_div_1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    }
    .child_div_2{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    }
     .child_budget{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left:15%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    }
    .child_value1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 15%;
    text-align: left;
    float:right;
    }
     .child_title{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .child_budget_number{
        padding-right: 20%;
    }
    .child_value1_number{
        padding-left: 20%;
    }

.boxbox {
    display: table;
    width: 99.8%;
    height: 160px;
    color: #454545;
    font-size:1.1vw;
}

.boxbox {
    float:left;
    display: table;
    width: 99.8%;
    height: 180px; 
    color: #454545;
}
.boxbox > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper2" style="height:160px;">
<div class="infobox" id="platform1">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform1_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform1_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform6">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform6_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform6_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform3">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #a15aa0; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform3_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform3_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform5">
<div class="boxbox" id="platform5">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #ff0102; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform5_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform5_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox" id="platform4">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #cac9c2; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform4_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform4_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox" id="platform2">
<div class="boxbox" id="platform2">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #8a3ab9; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform2_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform2_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: If yo u need to target the *5th* box, your css selector syntax should actually specify the number 5 between the parenthesis of the *pseudo-selector* `:nth-of-type`, e.g: `.infobox5:nth-of-type(5)`. `nth-of-type` refers to the `type` of element (in this case, a `div`) and *not the class*, so what the selectors `.infobox5:nth-of-type(3)` is really targeting is the **3rd** `div` *with* the class `.infobox5`

Comment: You can atleast  comment or rate as in which solution helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your direct child of class container infobox5 is overwriting the CSS color for your Jquery method. You have to remove it first and then use it as demonstrated below:

`Note- .eq(index) is better suited for your query in contrast to :nth-of-type(index). You can try them both and see it for yourself.`

Pointer:

- Clean up your CSS, a lot of unecessary styles have been implemented but for this query, as mentioned by the other answer as well .boxbox class is implementing its own color style and as mentioned the child of div with class infobox5 is also implementing its own color style which overrides the JQuery css being implemented on the parent container.

```js
$(".infobox5").eq(4).css("color", "green"); //Index starts from 0 for 1st element, 1 for 2nd and so on 4 for 5th element of type .infobox5
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.1vw!important;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.redSq {
  background-color: #ff000a;
  width: 117px;
  height: 241px;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  width: 99.8%;
  height: 180px;
  color: #454545;
  background-color: #dee9f3;
  //border: solid 1px #454545; 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row>.col-lg-6 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #454545;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

.boxes {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 5%;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#line {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.infobox {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #454545;
}

.infobox1 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.infobox2 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 49%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  //padding: 18px 0;
}

.infobox3 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 32.33%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  //padding: 18px 0;
}

.infobox4 {
  float: left;
  //min-height:150px;
  min-width: 23.9%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  //padding: 18px 0;
}

.infobox5 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 32.33%;
  margin: 0 0.5% 0.7%;
  //padding: 18px 0;
}

div.leftBox {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

div.rightBox {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.infocontentheader {
  //text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.8;
  //color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.infocontent {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

div#facebook.infocontentheader {
  background-color: #3c5999;
}

div#facebook.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

p#sTitle {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

p#bTitle {
  //font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

p#facebook_spend,
p#youtube_spend,
p#search_spend,
p#programmatic_spend,
p#instagram_spend,
p#twitter_spend {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

p#facebook_budget,
p#youtube_budget,
p#search_budget,
p#programmatic_budget,
p#instagram_budget,
p#twitter_budget {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

div#twitter.infocontentheader {
  background-color: #1da1f2;
}

div#twitter.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

div#programmatic.infocontentheader {
  background-color: #a15aa0;
}

div#display.parentbox {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: #fff;
}

div#video.parentbox {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #fff;
}

div#mixed.parentbox {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  color: #fff;
}

#programmatic div.infocontentheader {
  color: #fff;
}

div#programmatic.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

div#programmatic_value.infocontent {
  color: #000;
}

div#youtube.infocontentheader {
  background-color: #ff0102;
}

div#youtube.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

div#search.infocontentheader {
  background-color: #cac9c2;
}

div#search.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
}

div#instagram.infobox {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div#instagram.infobox img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#parent_div_1 {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #757476;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

#parent_div_2 {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #8D8D8D;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.parentbox {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 150px;
  /*background-color: #8D8D8D;*/
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.parentbox1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.parentbox2 {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.parentbox3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.child_div_1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.child_div_2 {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.child_budget {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 15%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.child_spend {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-right: 15%;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}

.child_title {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.child_budget_number {
  padding-right: 20%;
}

.child_spend_number {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.boxbox {
  display: table;
  width: 99.8%;
  height: 160px;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.boxbox {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  width: 99.8%;
  height: 180px;
}

.boxbox>.col-lg-6 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper2" style="height:160px;">
<div class="infobox infobox5" id="platform1">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform1_value1">353</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform1_value2">1,634</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox hidden" id="platform6">
<div class="boxbox" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform6_value1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform6_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox infobox5" id="platform5">
<div class="boxbox" >
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #a15aa0; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform5_value1">706</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform5_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox infobox5" id="platform3">
<div class="boxbox" id="platform3" >
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #ff0102; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform3_value1">404</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform3_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox infobox5" id="platform4">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #cac9c2; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform4_value1">353</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform4_value2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox infobox5" id="platform2">
<div class="boxbox" id="platform2" >
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #8a3ab9; min-width: 50px;">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">value1<br>
        <div id="platform2_value1">404</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">value2<br>
        <div id="platform2_value2">6,364</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: element.eq(n); where n is the index value of the element